# After upgrade to RXJS 6.5 fromPromise no longer availabe

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

in my code i had an interceptor which handled all outbound http Requests and added the token to it.
The code looked like this

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

const promise = this.storage.get('token');

return Observable.fromPromise(promise)
  .mergeMap(token => {
    const clonedReq = this.addToken(request, token);
    return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
      catchError(async err => {
        // Perhaps display an error for specific status codes here already?
        if (err.status === 400 && err.error.message === 'Failed to authenticate token.') {
          this.auth.logout(true);
        }

        if (err.status === 401 && err.error.error === 'TokenExpiredError') {
          this.auth.logout();
          // this.unauthorizedWatcher.getInterceptedSource().next(err.status);
        }

        let errorText = '';
        if (err.error) {
          errorText = err.error.message;
        } else if (err.statusText) {
          errorText = err.statusText;
        }

        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: errorText ? errorText : err.name,
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
          cssClass: 'error',
        });
        (await toast).present();

        // Pass the error to the caller of the function
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  });
}
```

since i upgraded from rxjs: "5.5.11" to rxjs: "6.5.1" fromPromise is no longer avail. How would i convert this line to valid 6.5.x jxjs code

Answer (score 2):

For RxJS 6+, you should replace the use of `fromPromise()` operator with the `from()` operator. In addition, you will have to use `pipe()` to chain your operators.

```
const promise = this.storage.get('token');

return from(promise)
   .pipe(
      mergeMap(token => {
        ..... 
      }),
   )
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from), the purpose of the `from()` operator is to

> Turn an array, promise, or iterable into an observable.

Comment: That creates a new error now  Type 'Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any> | Observable<...>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
  Type 'HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any> | Observable<...>' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
    Type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'Observable<never>' but required in type 'HttpUserEvent<any>'.ts(2322)